# useState is using the wrong value with a custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

In my React component, I have the following code:

```js
const [additionalGuestAmounts] = useState<RatePlan['additionalGuestAmounts']>(
  useAdditionalGuestAmounts(roomType, occupantsForBaseRate)
)
```

And here is my custom hook:

```js
const useAdditionalGuestAmounts = (
  roomType: RoomType,
  occupantsForBaseRate: number
): RatePlan['additionalGuestAmounts'] => {
  console.log('executing useAdditionalGuestAmounts hook')
  if (!roomType) {
    return []
  }
  console.log('returning array')
  return [
    {
      foo: 'bar'
    },
  ]
}
```

When I modify `roomType` from `null` to a value, it logs `'executing useAdditionalGuestAmounts hook'` and then `'returning array'`, however the value of `additionalGuestAmounts` is not updated; it stays as an empty array. Why is the value not being updated if the custom hook is being executed?

Comment: For an explanation why it doesn't work, take a look at the documentation of `useState`, especially the [initialState](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useState#parameters) parameter ("The value you want the state to be initially. It can be a value of any type, but there is a special behavior for functions. This argument is ignored after the initial render.")

Comment: Do you need to use state for this? From my point of view, you could just use a normal javascript function and calculate it based on the input parameters

Comment: @A_A Ah yes, that would make sense that it doesn't get updated. But if "This argument is ignored after the initial render", then why is the function being executed on every render? That seems inefficient to me.

Comment: @A_A Yes, I need to use state. I have removed the `setAdditionalGuestAmounts` function for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

The value that is passed in the `useState` hook is only the initial value of the state as explained on the documentation of the useState hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html, to make sure that the state is updated whenever the useAdditionalGuestAmounts hook is called we will have to call `setAdditionalGuestAmounts` with the new value. This would then look like:

```
    // Initial state
    const [additionalGuestAmounts, setAdditionalGuestAmounts] = useState<RatePlan['additionalGuestAmounts']>([])
    const useAdditionalGuestAmounts = (
        roomType: RoomType,
        occupantsForBaseRate: number
    ) => {
        if (!roomType) {
            return []
        }
 
        // Update the state, this causes the page to re-render
        setAdditionalGuestAmounts( [
            {
                foo: 'bar'
            },
        ])
    }
```

If you need the `useAdditionalGuestAmounts` to be called on page load you can use the `useEffect` hook for this (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: Custom react hooks [should](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks#passing-reactive-values-between-hooks) be [pure functions](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/keeping-components-pure). Setting the state inside a custom hook would therefore make it not pure, and is not recommended.

Comment: I don't think the `useAdditionalGuestAmounts` should be a hook to begin with, it acts like a function that just modifies the state

Comment: I agree. It's just since in your code the function name starts with "use", that makes it a hook and you're setting the state within the main body of the hook. In the end, I just used `useEffect` to change the value whenever `roomType` or
`occupantsForBaseRate` change. I think what was throwing me off was that the custom hook code was being executed on every re-render.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the additionalGuestAmounts state variable is not being updated when you modify roomTypeId because the useAdditionalGuestAmounts hook is not being called again. This is because the useAdditionalGuestAmounts hook is only called when the component is first rendered, and is not called again.

As stated previously by rowan, you can a useEffect hook inside the useAdditionalGuestAmounts hook.

```
const useAdditionalGuestAmounts = (
  roomType: RoomType,
  occupantsForBaseRate: number
): RatePlan['additionalGuestAmounts'] => {
  console.log('executing useAdditionalGuestAmounts hook')
  const [additionalGuestAmounts, setAdditionalGuestAmounts] = useState<
    RatePlan['additionalGuestAmounts']
  >([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!roomType) {
      return;
    }
    console.log('returning array');
    setAdditionalGuestAmounts([
      {
        foo: 'bar',
      },
      {
        foo: 'bar',
      },
      {
        foo: 'bar',
      },
      {
        foo: 'bar',
      },
      {
        foo: 'bar',
      },
    ]);
  }, [roomTypeId, occupantsForBaseRate]);

  return additionalGuestAmounts;
};
```

You also need to add the occupantsForBaseRate argument to the dependencies array, because the useAdditionalGuestAmounts hook depends on it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not quite true. The custom hook is called on every render, which is what was throwing me off, since I assumed it was being re-mounted for some reason. See: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-increment-decrement-forked-wu59jw?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Or from the [docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks#passing-reactive-values-between-hooks): "The code inside your custom Hooks will re-run during every re-render of your component. This is why, like components, custom Hooks need to be pure. Think of custom Hooks’ code as part of your component’s body!"